# Locking Ubuntu 20.04 kills bond interfaces

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan

Symptom: 2 bonds with static IPs  on 2 different Dual Port NICS.
works fine while logged on and session is active, but the second the session locks, or if the session is manually locked, the netplan interfaces disconnect.

Haven't tried independent static IPs to see if netplan service is terminating or if it's just reverting back to a non-user config.

As a possible work around, is there a way to set netplan config as root or default config so that it's not dependent to the user session?

Running QEMU KVM, so the impact is pretty significant.  Getting so annoyed I'm tempted to load Free version of VMWare on the internal SD Card module, but trying real hard to get better with open source systems.

Comment: Please provide more specific information. Specifically, update the question with the contents of your Netplan configuration file as well as the output of `ip a`. Also, is this a Desktop or Server installation?